# How to convert multi dimensional array to single dimensional array in php ?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want convert this multi dimensional array to single dimensions array

```
array([ca] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [userid] => 1 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [userid] => 10 ) 
       [2] => Array ( [userid] => 14 ) 
       [3] => Array ( [userid] => 16 ) 
       [4] => Array ( [userid] => 17 ) 
       [5] => Array ( [userid] => 18 ) 
       [6] => Array ( [userid] => 25 ) 
     )
```

Convert to following array

```
array ([ca] =>
        array(
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 10 
        [2] => 14 
        [3] => 16 
        [4] => 17 
        [5] => 18  
        [6] => 25 
     ))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have an attempt to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $res['ca'][] = $val['userid'];
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

And an example with array_walk:

```
array_walk(
    $array['ca'],
    function(&$item, $key) {
        return $item = $item['userid'];
    }
);
```